# whole body control with a TIAGo robot

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community,
I want to use a gamepad to control Tiago robot by PAL robotics. In order to control its arm, I used the moveit commander python interface. The idea was to read the current pose of the end effector, and increment it by a small value like 0.05 (m) based on the axis or the button pressed on the gamepad. Everything is working perfectly, however, I had to wait for the arm commander group to arrive at the desired pose.
`plan = group.go(wait=True)`
So the movement of the arm is no longer smooth, and if I change the wait argument to False the arm will start vibrating and not moving anywhere, Any solution please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403392/whole-body-control-with-a-tiago-robot/) by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2022-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2022-07-05**:
If it is vibrating the moveit is continuously planning and giving new goals, I would recommend you to stop planning and doing anything if you are within a certain tolerance and until you receive a new command from the gamepad

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-07-05**:
So, you mean that i can't change the goal in real time, and I have to wait for each goal to be reached ?
However, I don't want to wait for it to reach I want to change the goal in real time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-07-06**:
Then you perhaps should not be using the MoveIt commander, as it's not really meant for this kind of thing.

Perhaps #q261368 can clarify some things (it's a bit of an older Q&A, but parts are still relevant).

For real-time servoing, you might want to look at [moveit_servo](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/realtime_servo/realtime_servo_tutorial.html). It exists for both ROS 1 and ROS 2.

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-07-07**:
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a trick to that. I used only the plan method provided by the moveit commander to get a plan, and instead of using the go method I published the trajectory to the arm_controller/command topic and that helps a lot.

---

Originally posted by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) with karma: 42 on 2022-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0